# Why did the welfare state succeed in Bismarck's Germany but lagged in 20th-century Britain?

Tags: germany, britain, economy

Otto von Bismarck pioneered the welfare state in Germany and Bismarck was/is greatly respected by Germans.

Pre-World War I British Liberal Party made welfare reforms after the 1906 general election. One of the reasons was that the success of social legislation in Bismarck's Germany made leading Liberals in the UK such as David Lloyd George and Winston Churchill want to put forward similar legislation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberal_welfare_reforms).

Post-World War II British Labour Party implemented welfare state policies after their victory in the 1945 general election. The economic result lagged Germany's. When Margaret Thatcher came into power, she reversed the welfare policies which did not seem to be working as expected and pushed through free market-oriented policies. On the other hand, today's welfare policies in Germany still remains Bismarckian in principle.

Why did the welfare state succeed in Bismarck Germany but lagged in 20th-century Britain?

Comment: Hold on a sec, your comparison is flawed - before you compare Bismarck's policies to British Labour model 1945 you should first compare them to the reforms made by British Liberals in 1906-1914. Look up Lloyd George's "People's Budget" for example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/People's_Budget As it stands the question is poorly constructed and misleads. -1, I am afraid, till is fixed.

Comment: Well, yeah, comparing late 19th century Germany with post-war Britain is not perhaps a useful comparison.

Comment: @Felix Goldberg: The aftermath of the Liberal welfare reforms did not look good either. The timing coincided with the decline of the British empire. On the other hand, one of the causes for these reforms was that  the success of social legislation in Bismarck's Germany made leading Liberals in the UK such as David Lloyd George and Winston Churchill want to put forward similar legislation. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberal_welfare_reforms

Comment: @Felix Goldberg: I edited the question to include the Liberals part but kept the Labour Party portion because of the wonderful answer already provided by Lennart Regebro which compared Bismarck Germany and Labour Britain

Comment: @curious I should at this point note that Germany *still* has a Bismarckian system. The question can rather be reinterpreted as why the welfare state succeeded in Germany but failed in Britain (perhaps focused even on the time between 1950 and 1980). Such a comparison would be more fair.

Comment: Okay, I reversed my downvote. Also editing a bit for a more even tone, if you don't object (feel free to revert my edit, the downvote reversal is unconditional ;)

Comment: However, I am not sure what is the point of mentioning the decline of the British empire here - you don't mean to suggest it declined *because* of the reforms, do you?

Comment: "The economic result was terrible until Margaret Thatcher came into power" I'm not sure this is the makings of a decent question. Please rephrase. If you think "Post-war consensus" had drawbacks (and it did) be more specific.

Comment: @Nathan Cooper: I edited the part on "The economic result was terrible until Margaret Thatcher came into power"

Comment: @Felix Goldberg: The part on the decline of the British empire was not really necessary because it is hard to prove or disprove whether the welfare policies was a strong cause. I have removed it. The fact that Margaret Thatcher reversed the welfare policies was proof that the welfare policies did not work well in Britain, at least when compared to Germany.

Comment: @Lennart Regebro: thanks for the suggestion. I have rephrased the question to ask why the welfare state succeeded in Germany but failed in Britain

Comment: I don't share your historical narrative, but I do think this is a better question now. Somewhat. Downvote removed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are probably several reasons, and it's likely impossible to answer without writing a book, and most of the reasons are not political but has rather to do with economics.

One of the major reasons is based in fundamental economics. The [Bismarckian](http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/pages/frontline/sickaroundtheworld/countries/models.html) welfare state is based on social insurance, ie, the government pays for an insurance that the welfare recipient can use as they best see fit. The most clear example is in health care, where the Bismarckian health cases system has a tax-funded health insurance which you can use to pay for to a largely privately run health care system. This preserves [competition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economics_in_One_Lesson) and [ensures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wealth_of_Nations) [efficiency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitalism_and_Freedom) better than the British system (often called the Beverige model), where the health care system is not funding individual health care, but instead funding state owned health care. This creates a monolithic bureaucratic system where the health care is overpriced. The result is typically that the rich pays for better private health-care, while everyone else are forced to endure long queues and waiting lists for operations, fueling resentment and dissatisfaction with the system.

The second major reason is political, and that is that the unions in Britain used their power to a large extent to block change and economic reforms. When industry was going badly, the Unions would not accept changes as this would have resulted in cut downs, instead they striked to prevent the cut downs, which just resulted in companies shutting down completely. This resulted in a conflict between the unions who were unrealistically blocking reform, and the union-supported government who tried to make reforms and still keep the unions happy at the same time.

This impossible situation and the resulting economic decline was then only reverted when a conservative government took over, as this government did not need nor want the support of the unions and went through with the economic reforms despite the unions opposition.

Countries with similar situations to the UK (like Denmark and Sweden) saw similar development. Both Denmark and Sweden has also, like the UK, made many free-market reforms, and both are busy improving their health-care problems by moving the a Bismarckian system (but not the UK, yet).

Comment: The key points of your answer were (1) German health care system funds the individual health care (2) British health care funds state-owned health care. Bureaucrats are well-known for bad spending. Individuals allocate capital much better than bureaucrats. I wish I could upvote your answer twice. Thanks for answering my questions as always

Comment: There is a slight problem here: German healthcare is significantly more expensive than UK healthcare (total health expenditure is 11.3% of GDP in Germany compared with 9.4% in the UK; German GDP per capita is higher too) but life expectancy at birth is marginally higher in the UK (81.1 years in the UK compared with 80.8 in Germany).  It seems that the larger number of health interventions in Germany do not actually produce healthier people.

Comment: @Henry 1. When people are allowed to control their health care expense they will generally spend quite  alot. That's expected. 2. life expectancy at birth is not the only (or even a good) measure of what health care provides. 3. This is not exactly a good place to discuss health care policies.

Comment: @LennartRegebro: You said "the welfare state succeeded in Germany but failed in Britain", so I hardly started the discussion. Private spending on health is also higher in Germany than the UK, so perhaps Germans find their insurance system less sufficient than UK citizens find their state health provision.

Comment: @Henry: No curious did. That's the base assumption for the question, and I think he is correct. And the higher private spending is the reason for the higher total spending, as already mentioned. It doesn't seem to me that further discussion in this topic with you will be constructive.

Comment: Citations needed. Seems to be born out a dislike for the British system, rather than any real knowledge of the German system and therefore the comparison.

Comment: @NathanCooper Citations: Fundamental economics knowledge; [Health care research](http://www.healthpowerhouse.com/); [WHO world health reports](http://www.who.int/whr/previous/en/), etc. Bureaucracies, state ownership and control just doesn't work very efficiently. That's not an opinion or a "dislike" it's a fundamental economic fact that has been universally accepted by all serious economists since [1776](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wealth_of_Nations).

Comment: Yes, however. Do state owned enterprises work in general is not the question. Your answer should be relevant to and informed by the situation in 20th Britain and Germany. Right now your answer provides a weak historical context for your opinion. The view doesn't necessarily need to change, but the rigor does. Understand, while I'm not hiding the fact that I disagree with your political position, that is not the point I am making and we are not going to discuss that disagreement on history SE.

Comment: @NathanCooper: "Do state owned enterprises work in general is not the question." - It is not even **a** question. This is not a political position, disagreeing with it is comparable with denying evolution. The question then becomes what exactly you want references for.

Comment: "The result is typically that the rich pays for better private health-care, while everyone else are forced to endure long queues and waiting lists for operations, fueling resentment and dissatisfaction with the system." Which the UK "solved" by making it illegal to use any healthcare not provided by the NHS in typical fashion of government run anything whatsoever.

Comment: @jwenting Really? That's pretty shocking. Links?

Comment: @LennartRegebro that's what many UK friends have told me, that the NHS refuses to treat patients who have had treatment for anything outside the NHS because "that would impose on the NHS the cost of correcting errors made by sub-quality care performed outside our rigid standards" (which is a laugh as the NHS is known far and wide for its horrible quality). http://www.ft.com/cms/s/0/a6731edc-2002-11e0-a6fb-00144feab49a.html might be related and people just misunderstand it (including NHS staff) to mean no foreign care is allowed at all.

Comment: Bloody pay walls... Ah well, Google to the rescue:  http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:FuFXy2e4oWcJ:www.ft.com/cms/s/0/a6731edc-2002-11e0-a6fb-00144feab49a.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&client=ubuntu#axzz2l4qVMn83

Comment: @jwenting In any case, that's shocking, but not actually surprising. There are related machinations to destroy non-governmental health care in Sweden.

Answer (score 2):

Bismarck's "welfare" was what Americans would call "workfare." The German version advocated pensions for retired people and health insurance for workers, both of which help people to work better.

The English version of the welfare state was "true" welfare. The idea was to use unions to allow workers to work LESS, while enjoying higher wages, not work more efficiently.